# my pytorch model is not learning anything and the loss is just oscillating

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, classification

building a multi-class classification model using PyTorch
that classifies the type of the crime baised on 2 inputs
from that data set time,location as in

```
# main data 
df = pd.read_csv('abstract_data.csv',delimiter=',')
```

that looks like so ...(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho7oh.png)

```
# extracting the 2 inputs from the dataset 
inputs_list=['TIME OCC','AREA']
inputs=df[inputs_list].to_numpy()
inputs.shape    # of shape (893672, 2)
```

```
# extraction the labels 
y=df['Crm Cd']
```

looks as

```
0         510
1         330
2         480
3         343
4         354
         ... 
893667    740
893668    230
893669    625
893670    745
893671    210
Name: Crm Cd, Length: 893672, dtype: int64
```

here the classes are made up of 3 digits integer
and there are '138' different classes
that i extracted using the following code

```
# unique classes 
unq=y.unique()
```

[as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpllG.png)
as far as i know that in order to make a classification model with 138 classes
i need to format the origonal output labels that was made up of '3 digits number'
to a suitable numbers from the range of 138
and i did that with that code

```
# mapping origonal classes numbers into the new classes ids 
y2=[]
for i in y:
    #print(f'i: {i}')
    for index, element in enumerate(unq):
        if i == element:
            y2.append(index)
            break
output=np.array(y2)
```

thus now the clases are with in range

```
# normlization of inputs data 
inputs = (inputs - inputs.min(axis=0)) / (inputs.max(axis=0) - inputs.min(axis=0)) 

# converting to tensors 
inputs_tensors=torch.tensor(data=inputs,dtype=torch.float32)
labels_tensors=torch.tensor(data=output,dtype=torch.float32)
labels_tensors=labels_tensors.type(torch.LongTensor)

# train & test split 
size_split=int(0.9*len(inputs_tensors))
train_inputs, train_labels = inputs_tensors[:size_split], labels_tensors[:size_split]
test_inputs, test_labels= inputs_tensors[size_split:], labels_tensors[size_split:]

# creating a custom data set 
lass CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, inputs, labels):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.labels = labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_data = self.inputs[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return input_data, label
    
train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_inputs, train_labels)
test_dataset = CustomDataset(test_inputs, test_labels)

# dataloader 
BATCH_SIZE = 32 
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)

# device setting 
device= 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

# main training loop
def train_test_loop(
               epochs:int,
               model:torch.nn.Module,
               loss_fn:torch.nn.Module,
               optimizer:torch.optim.Optimizer,
               accuracy_fn,
               train_dataloader:torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
               test_dataloader:torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
               device:torch.device=device):

  from tqdm.auto import tqdm
  import numpy as np 
  from timeit import default_timer as timer
  loss_hist=[]
  epoch_hist=[]
  train_time_start_= timer()
  epochs = epochs
  model.to(device)
  train_acc = 0
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_loss = 0
    print(f'epoch: {epoch}\n-----')
    for batch,(X,y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
      
      X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
      model.train()

      y_pred=model(X)
      
      loss=loss_fn(y_pred,y)
      loss_hist.append(loss)
      train_loss += loss
      train_acc += accuracy_fn(y_true=y, y_pred=y_pred.argmax(dim=1))
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      loss.backward()

      optimizer.step()
      epoch_hist.append(batch)
      if batch % 400 == 0:
        print(f'  batch: {batch} | loss: {loss} | ')
        print(f"  Looked at {batch * len(X)}/{len(train_dataloader.dataset)} samples")
        
    train_loss /= len(train_dataloader)
    print(f'total_loss: {train_loss}')
    train_acc /= len(train_dataloader)
    print(f'  acc: {train_acc} | ')

# base model 
class MLPClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 100)  # Input layer
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(100, 512)  # Hidden layer
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(512, 200)
        self.output = nn.Linear(200, 138)   # Output layer with 138 classes

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.linear3(x))
        x = self.output(x)
        return torch.softmax(x, dim=1) 

model = MLPClassifier()

# optiizer and loss 
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

i also tried the adam optimizer but it was the same result

```
# model training 
def accuracy_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    """Calculates accuracy between truth labels and predictions.

    Args:
        y_true (torch.Tensor): Truth labels for predictions.
        y_pred (torch.Tensor): Predictions to be compared to predictions.

    Returns:
        [torch.float]: Accuracy value between y_true and y_pred, e.g. 78.45
    """
    correct = torch.eq(y_true, y_pred).sum().item()
    acc = (correct / len(y_pred)) * 100
    return acc

accuracy_fn=accuracy_fn
t1=train_test_loop(epochs=10,model=model,loss_fn=loss,accuracy_fn=accuracy_fn,optimizer=optimizer,train_dataloader=train_dataloader,test_dataloader=test_dataloader)
```

this will run and the loss will keep on the loss oscillation
between '4.908379554748535 and 4.708379554748535'
and never converges even tho i tried everything like changing the model layers and parameters
and the learning rate and optimizers
i realy feel hope-less

i was expecting it to converge but it didnt it was just oscillating
with the loss

i tried changing 'model archetecture, layers and parameters,
optimizers ,learning rate'
but nothing worked
im suspecting there is something wrong with the dataset format or something but im not sure

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution but my suggestion would be to start small and simple and then sequentially add more complexity. This is often a good idea when you design a machine learning model.

So I would start by selecting only two classes from your data and try to build a model that is able to predict them. And if this goes well, add more classes and see how this goes.
Also start with a really simple model, three layers, and small layers.

Another thing is that you have only two features but 138 classes. This can be a problem.
And are you even sure that there is a relation between those features and classes than can be learned?
What would also be interesting to know is how much data you have for each class. Is it equal for each class or have some classes a lot of data and some only a few samples.

Comment: thank you for your time and help Frede. u really gave me a new way of thinking that i wasnt aware of it 
i will try this and then scale.
and yes i think there is a relation in the dataset 'as i hope' but im still learning how to plot the data am sure if i could plot the data id see the relation 
thank you again tho !

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you!